# How to v-for loop a nested navigation in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a multi-level navigation using Vue.js.

When I try to use `v-for` inside my `v-for` in the parent navigation element, Vue throws an error and says `item is undefined`.

HTML:

```
<nav id="hf-nav">
  <a v-for="item in itemLinks" :href="`${item.link}`"></a>
    {{ item.title }}
    <nav v-if="item.subItems">
      <a v-for="sub in item.subItems" :href="`${sub.link}`">{{ sub.title }}</a>
    </nav>
  </a>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#hf-main',
  data: {
    homepage: true,
    itemLinks: [
      { title: 'Home', link: './' },
      {
        title: 'Diensten',
        link: './diensten',
        subItems: [
          { title: 'Elektromontage', link: './elektromontage' },
          { title: 'Installatietechniek', link: './installatietechniek' },
          { title: 'Schoonmaak', link: './schoonmaak' },
          { title: 'Overige diensten', link: './overige-diensten' },
        ],
      },
      { title: 'Over H&F', link: './over-hf' },
      { title: 'Contact', link: './contact' },
    ],
  },
})
```

I want Vue to loop and check if there's a second level in the inside an itemLinks object, and if so I want Vue to execute another loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the closing `</a>` tag at the end of this line:

```html
<a v-for="item in itemLinks" :href="`${item.link}`">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

The `item` for the `v-for` will only be defined within the scope of this tag, so the lines that follows won't know anything about it.

My guess would be that you were aiming for this:

```html
<nav id="hf-nav">
    <template v-for="item in itemLinks">
        <a :href="`${item.link}`">{{ item.title }}</a>
        <nav v-if="item.subItems">
            <a v-for="sub in item.subItems" :href="`${sub.link}`">{{ sub.title }}</a>
        </nav>
    </template>
</nav>
```

I'm a little surprised that your editor wasn't warning you that the HTML tags weren't balanced. The closing `</a>` tag on the penultimate line of your code doesn't have a matching opening tag.

Incidentally, there's no need to use backticks for `` :href="`${item.link}`" ``, you can just write `:href="item.link"`. Likewise for `:href="sub.link"`.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. Thanks skirtle! :-)